How to authenticate to Azure AD using java SDK
I am trying to create an authentication method to autheticate to azure ad for adding an removal of users via my java code. I have a free tier account setup for the same. below is the method I used for authentication:
   try {
            final AzureProfile profile = new AzureProfile(AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
            final TokenCredential credential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
                .authorityHost(profile.getEnvironment().getActiveDirectoryEndpoint())
                .build();

            AzureResourceManager azureResourceManager = AzureResourceManager
                .configure()
                .withLogLevel(HttpLogDetailLevel.BASIC)
                .authenticate(credential, profile)
                .withDefaultSubscription();

            runSample(azureResourceManager, profile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

public static boolean runSample(AzureResourceManager azureResourceManager, AzureProfile profile) {
        final String userEmail = Utils.randomResourceName(azureResourceManager, "test", 15);
        final String userName = userEmail.replace("test", "Test ");
        final String spName = Utils.randomResourceName(azureResourceManager, "sp", 15);
        final String raName1 = Utils.randomUuid(azureResourceManager);
        final String raName2 = Utils.randomUuid(azureResourceManager);
        final String groupEmail1 = Utils.randomResourceName(azureResourceManager, "group1", 15);
        final String groupEmail2 = Utils.randomResourceName(azureResourceManager, "group2", 15);
        final String groupName1 = groupEmail1.replace("group1", "Group ");
        final String groupName2 = groupEmail2.replace("group2", "Group ");
        String spId = "";
        try {
            // ============================================================
            // Create a user

            System.out.println("Creating an AD user " + userName + "...");
//
            ActiveDirectoryUser user = azureResourceManager.accessManagement().activeDirectoryUsers()
                    .define(userName)
                    .withEmailAlias(userEmail)
                    .withPassword(Utils.password())
                    .create();
//
            System.out.println("Created AD user " + userName);
            Utils.print(user);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Did not create Service Principal in Azure. No clean up is necessary");
            }
}

I passed 
these details in the environment. Where client secret I extracted after registering an application in the portal. I am not able to complete the authentication by the above logic. Can anyone please help me here ?

Please edit your question and include 2 things: 1) Your complete code (we don't know what's happening in your runSample code) and 2) The error you are getting.

@GauravMantri Added. Please check

You can make use of Microsoft Graph Java SDK to authenticate Azure AD for user's addition and removal.
Initially, I registered one application and granted User.ReadWrite.All permission of Application type with consent as below:

Now, I created one client secret in above app registration and noted it's value like this:

In my case, I ran below sample code to create user in Azure AD and got response like this:
Main.java:
package org.example;

import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.PasswordProfile;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "appId";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "secretValue";
    private static final String TENANT_ID = "tenantId";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                    .clientId(CLIENT_ID)
                    .clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .tenantId(TENANT_ID)
                    .build();

            List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
            TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
                    scopes,
                    credential
            );

            GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                    .builder()
                    .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
                    .buildClient();

            createUser(graphClient);

            // delete a user
            // deleteUser(graphClient, "<USER_ID>");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createUser(GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient) {
        User user = new User();
        user.displayName = "User Name";
        user.mailNickname = "username";
        user.userPrincipalName = "username@yourdomain.onmicrosoft.com";
        user.accountEnabled = true;
        user.passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile();
        user.passwordProfile.password = "P@ssw0rd!";
        user.passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false;

        User createdUser = graphClient.users()
                .buildRequest()
                .post(user);

        System.out.println("Created User with ID: " + createdUser.id);
        System.out.println("Created User with Name: " + createdUser.displayName);
    }

    private static void deleteUser(GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient, String userId) {
        graphClient.users(userId)
                .buildRequest()
                .delete();
        System.out.println("Deleted User with ID: " + userId);
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where new user created successfully as below:

Before executing the code above, ensure that the necessary dependencies are installed in your Java project:
pom.xml:
<dependencies>
        <!-- Azure Identity library for authentication -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Microsoft Graph SDK for Java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
            <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

Reference:
Create User - Microsoft Graph v1.0

Thanks a lot. It worked for creation of a user. I will explore the graph approach for addition into the group as well.

Glad to be of help! Feel free to post new question and share the link here if you face any issue while working with groups : )
